# Detect if any character from a data frame is present in a list of strings

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of strings that I want to check if they contain any character that is dynamically created in a separate data frame. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#Create data frame of Values to check against
df <- data.frame(Value = 33:53) #these values will be dynamic

#Add in Utf8 conversion
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Utf8 = intToUtf8(Value))

#create data frame of strings to check
df_check <- data.frame(string = c("CDEFFFFFFFEFADFFFFF","CDEFFFFFFF&FADFFFFF"))
```

I now want to check if the strings contain any of the characters that are in `df`, and output either `TRUE` or `FALSE` in a new column. I don't want to use a standard regular expression to check if any of the characters are there, because the length of `df` can be variable and certain characters can be omitted.
I can check individual characters like so (which gives me the desired output but for only one character):

```
df_check <- df_check %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(contains_chr = list(str_detect(string,"&")))

> string                contains_chr
> CDEFFFFFFFE!FADFFFFF  FALSE
> CDEFFFFFFF&!FADFFFFF  TRUE
```

How can I make the 'contains_chr' column `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on whether any of the characters in `df` appeared? I tried this but it fails:

```
df_check <- df_check %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(contains_chr = list(str_detect(string,df)))

Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `contains_chr`.
ℹ `contains_chr = list(str_detect(string, df))`.
x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "c('rowwise_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
```

I don't know how to check for each of the characters in `df$Utf8`. I probably could put it into a for-loop for each row in `df`, but there are millions of strings and this seems like it will be quite slow.